# c++ member function error: expected a ',' or '...' before '.' token

Tags: c++, string, class, constructor, linker

So I wrote a program in Visual Studio 2015 and tried transferring it over to Ubuntu. And I've been running into nothing but problems.

I have a class called "InputData" with a constructor which takes two strings to put into an ifstream:

```
class InputData {
( ... )
public:
    InputData(string filea.c_str(), string fileb.c_str());
}
```

and in my constructor, I have

```
InputData::InputData(string filea.c_str(), string fileb.c_str()) 
{
    ifstream instream;
    instream.open(filea.c_str());
    ( ... )
```

and finally in my main function I have

```
InputData x ("firstfile.csv", "secondfile.csv");
```

However, when I try to link these together and compile, I get the error:

```
expected a ',' or '...' before '.' token
  InputData(string filea.c_str(), string fileb.c_str());
                       ^
```

I've never seen this type of error before and I have no idea what's wrong with it. Can anyone help?

(also, I'm using .cstr( ) because my compiler for some reason is not compatible with or is not updated to c++11. I get another error if I don't use cstr.)

Comment: `InputData(string filea.c_str(), string fileb.c_str());` This is invalid syntax. It would not compile in MSVC as well. `InputData(std::string filea, std::string fileb);` should work if you had included `<string>` header.

Comment: I tried that, but I get the error "no matching function call to std::basic_ifstream", even if I compile with --std=c++11.

Comment: `InputData(string filea.c_str(), string fileb.c_str());` means `InputData(char*,  char*);` so is `char*` a string class?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is because in the constructor declaration each of the parameters must have a specified type and a variable *name* for that type, just like any C++ function. But variable names cannot include the `'.'` character, hence the error: `filea.c_str()` is not a valid variable name. It is a function call.

So your constructor should be something like `InputData(string filea, string fileb)`.

To compile as `C++11` use the gcc compiler flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: I tried that, but I get the error "no matching function call to std::basic_ifstream", even if I compile with --std=c++11.

Comment: You would need to tell me the whole error message, which should say where in the code the problem occurred. Btw, I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but it should have been `-std=c++11`. I have edited my answer.